# How to redirect to another page after image gets cropped and uploaded using cropperJS and php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cropperjs

I am using CropperJS Library, PHP and jQuery. After the image gets cropped with CropperJS, Using jQuery I call the `image_upload.php` page and when the image successfully uploads to server I want the page to refresh such that the image is displayed on all the pages where its path is called from database.
The problem that I am facing is that after pressing the crop button on `bootstrap modal,` image gets cropped and uploaded, **when the bootstrap modal closes by default the page doesn't reloads as I want it to**. How can I load a new link or refresh the same page that will display cropped image on desired locations? Kindly help

Here is the html

```
<!-- Upload Profile Picture -->
<div class="container" align="center">
            <!-- <br />
            <br /> -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="image_area">
                        <form method="post">
                            <label for="upload_image">
                                <img width="200px" src="
                                <?php
                                  if($result['dp']==""){
                                    echo "uploads/default.png";
                                  }else{echo $result['dp'];}  
                                ?>
                                " style="border-radius:50%;" id="uploaded_image" class="img-responsive img-circle" />
                                <div class="overlay">
                                    <div class="text">Click to Change Profile Image</div>
                                </div>
                                <input type="file" name="image" class="image" id="upload_image" style="display:none" required>
                            </label>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title">Crop Image Before Upload</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="img-container">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        <img src="" id="sample_image" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="preview"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" id="crop" class="btn btn-primary">Crop</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>          
        </div>
```

Here is the jquery

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    var $modal = $('#modal');

    var image = document.getElementById('sample_image');

    var cropper;

    $('#upload_image').change(function(event){
        var files = event.target.files;

        var done = function(url){
            image.src = url;
            $modal.modal('show');
        };

        if(files && files.length > 0)
        {
            reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(event)
            {
                done(reader.result);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
        }
    });

    $modal.on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
        cropper = new Cropper(image, {
            aspectRatio: 1,
            viewMode: 3,
            preview:'.preview'
        });
    }).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
        cropper.destroy();
        cropper = null;
    });

    $('#crop').click(function(){
        canvas = cropper.getCroppedCanvas({
            width:400,
            height:400
        });

        canvas.toBlob(function(blob){
            url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
            reader.onloadend = function(){
                var base64data = reader.result;
                $.ajax({
                    url:'display_upload.php',
                    method:'POST',
                    data:{image:base64data},
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                        $modal.modal('hide');
                        $('#uploaded_image').attr('src', data);
                    }
                });
            };
        });
    });
    
});
</script>
```

Here is the php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['image']))
{
    $data = $_POST['image'];

    ////data:image/png;base64,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

    $image_array_1 = explode(";", $data);

    //base64,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

    $image_array_2 = explode(",", $image_array_1[1]);  
    $data = base64_decode($image_array_2[1]);

//my image name
$profile_id = $result['sid'];
//my image name
    $image_name = 'uploads/' .'display_'.$profile_id. '.png';

    file_put_contents($image_name, $data);
    echo $image_name;

//my database image name
$query = "UPDATE users SET dp = '$image_name' WHERE email = '$email'";
$data = mysqli_query($conn,$query); 
}
if($data)
                    {      
                        echo('<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; URL=profile.php?message=success"> ');}
                    
                else {
                        echo('<script> alert("Error");</script>');
                    }
?>
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32391315)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reload the page, on modal close using location.reload();

```
    $modal.on('hide.bs.modal', function() {
        location.reload();
    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much... I changed this part of jQuery .on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
  cropper.destroy();
    cropper = null;
    location.href='profile.php';
 });